# OWIN bearer token not working with Authorize when invalid

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, authorization, owin

I'm ripping my hair out. I am successfully creating a bearer token during a login. When I pass that token to my Authorized api controller everything works as expected.

If I do not pass a token or pass an invalid token I get this error message:

An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AccountsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."

I am injecting objects into my controller so I do not have a parameterless constructor. Regardless, shouldn't an unauthorized response be sent back?

Here is my setup for OWIN:

```
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
        Provider = new OauthServerProvider()
    };

    // Token Generation
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

Thanks, 
Paul

Comment: This (rather hard-to-understand) error can be caused by something going wrong when your dependency resolver tries to create the instances that are injected as parameters into the AccountsController constructor, for example if the constructor of the object that you tries to inject into AccountsController throws an exception. That exception is "swallowed" by the framework, and you only get the error you are describing... So try to understand what happens when object is created in your scenario. I usually diagnose these things by temporarily removing DI in order to see the actual exceptions...

Answer (score 1):

The default ASP.NET mechanism that builds controllers expects a parameterless constructor unless you use an IoC container and explicitly define how the controller should resolve dependencies.

The easy way to fix this is creating a parameterless constructor and call the constructor with parameters like this:

```
public TaskController()
    : this(new TaskService(new TaskRepository()))
{

}

public TaskController(ITaskService taskService)
{
    this.taskService = taskService;
}
```

The problem here is that your DI is not useful anymore.
You have to configure your DI in the Startup class.

I show you an example in Castle Windsor:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureOAuth(app);

    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    config.Filters.Add(new WebApiAuthorizeAttribute());

    ...

    // Dependency Resolver
    var container = new WindsorContainer().Install(new WebApiControllersInstaller());
    var httpDependencyResolver = new WindsorDependencyResolver(container);
    config.DependencyResolver = httpDependencyResolver;

    //Uncomment next lines for Composition Root DI configuration intead of Dependency Resolver
    //var container = new WindsorContainer().Install(new WebApiControllersInstaller());
    //config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new WindsorCompositionRoot(container));

}
```